# Linking against libusb on Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, linker, makefile, ld

We're trying to compile some code on an Ubuntu box that requires libusb but we keep getting "undefined reference to" errors when it tries to link against it.

The code in question is this one:
https://gitorious.org/minibox-dcdcusb/minibox-dcdcusb

It requires libusb so I install that:

```
apt-get install libusb libusb-dev
```

Then I run make and get the following errors:

```
➜  minibox-dcdcusb git:(master) ✗ make                    
cc -Wall  main.c -o dcdc-usb `pkg-config --libs libusb` -lm -L. -ldcdc-usb
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_driver_np'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_interrupt_read'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_busses'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_devices'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_set_configuration'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_interrupt_write'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_control_msg'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_set_altinterface'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_init'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_set_debug'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_open'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_claim_interface'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `floor'
./libdcdc-usb.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_busses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dcdc-usb] Error 1
```

I have verified that pkg-config is reporting the proper config params:

```
➜  minibox-dcdcusb git:(master) ✗ pkg-config --libs libusb
-lusb
```

And I've made sure that the binaries are where they're supposed to be:

```
➜  minibox-dcdcusb git:(master) ✗ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    37 des  3 13:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42998 des  3 13:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    41 des  3 13:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
```

And I've even made sure that the references that the linker seems to be complaining about are actually in the libusb binaries:

- http://pastie.org/9156632
- http://pastie.org/9156633

(spoiler: all the symbols that the linker complains about seem to be there)

Finally, I ran the compile command with -Wl,--verbose to see exactly what binaries the linker was picking up and it seems that it is in fact picking up the correct binaries but it just isn't able to link against them. Here is the output of that:

- http://pastie.org/9156644

I'm quite lost as to what could possibly be the problem here? Why isn't the linker able to link against libusb?

Comment: Order of arguments to gcc can matter. Does it work if you put the pkg-config call before the source and output arguments?

Comment: Nope... I tried that already and just verified again now that this doesn't have any effect. In fact I read somewhere that the linker information should come _after_ the source argument that requires that library.

Comment: I can never remember which order is which I just know that it sometimes causes problems. And actually I just noticed that this is complaining about the symbols in the library not the binary. You may need `-Wl,-E` here to export the symbols from your binary since you aren't linking against libusb dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why isn't the linker able to link against libusb?

It is able to, but when the linker sees that library it doesn't have any undefined references to symbols in libusb, so it just moves on and ignores it. Later the linker sees libdcdc-usb, which has undefined references to symbols in libusb, but it's too late by then, the linker has already closed libusb and stopped looking at it.

As the comment says, order of linker arguments matters, but the comment suggests moving them earlier, which is the wrong way round.

> In fact I read somewhere that the linker information should come after the source argument that requires that library.

It's not just "linker arguments after source files" you need to order the libraries so that libraries that provide symbol definitions come after the objects that need those definitions.

`libdcdc-usb` depends on `libusb` so `libusb` has to come *later*, so move the `pkg-config` call to the end.

Comment: Friggin brilliant! I had to move the -lm as well but after that it works! Thank you!

Comment: That's because the other libs depend on `libm` and it doesn't depend on them.